# Marshall.OffsetOf replacement on .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, interop

I'm investigating some pinvoke/interop pb on Windows Mobile (Compact Framework 3.5). 
I would like to print field offsets and size of structures shared between managed and native sides to check if that's coherent. Ultimately I would like to automate the test on the device for every such struct used in my project.

Unfortunately Marshall.OffsetOf isn't available on the compact framework.

Is there a replacement solution ?

Can you think of another way to test if struct definition is in sync between managed and native side when running on the device ?

Comment: Have you considered a test that just populates a struct with known values in native and then reading them from CF and vice versa?

Comment: Use the debugger's Memory window to sort this out.